# How to detect and control the phone lock/unlock on android?

Tags: android

I want to make that the phone ask a question(from database) when the phone is locked (locked =  the keyboard is locked ) and the user want to unlock. If the answer is correct then the phone is unlocked, else the phone ask another question.

I don't know how to detect the unlock and unlock/lock the phone when I want.

Please, help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to have a look on [Device Policy Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) and [Device Admin tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). You can lock the screen by a simple sample of code like:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);  
dpm.lockNow();
```

For the detection, you can follow this tutorial http://chandan-tech.blogspot.fr/2010/10/handling-screen-lock-unlock-in-android.html, it's very clear.