# I need to detect whether lockScreen is on or off on android phone

Tags: android

I need to detect whether **lockScreen** is on or off on android phone.

This is not exactly about lock type. Android Phone security settings allow user to set PIN or graphic pattern screen lock type. A lot of devices show lockScreen BEFORE user can enter PIN or pattern.
So we have three actions to-do to start work with launcher or apps:

1. Press screen turn on/off hardware button on device
2. Swipe on screen to go though lockscreen
3. enter unlock combination (pin or pattern)

Some devices don't show lockscreen so than we have:

1. Press screen turn on/off hardware button on device
2. enter unlock combination (pin or pattern)

[lock screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zts0M.png)

[enter pattern screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0PPp.png)

Often user can turn lockscreen on of off by choosing creen lock options. Theese options in most cases called **None** and **Swipe**

I have spent an hour to know out how to determine whether lockscreen is on or off using official android API but FAILed.
If there is no absolutely stable solution for all lockable android devices - so may be there possibility to determine if lockscreen is on (just 'on' - without 'off') on MOST devices.

Comment: checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356852/how-to-detect-and-control-the-phone-lock-unlock-on-android ? hope it will be helpful

Comment: No. That's not what I am looking for.